# R: Square buffer around points

Tags: r, r-sf, r-sp, terra

I've been trying to figure it out how to create square buffers around points, but the closest I've came it's to generate a diamond shaped buffer using terra::buffer with quadsegs = 1. Reproducible code below. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

PS. Something went wrong when uploading the plot, but I believe it's a stackoverflow issue

```
library(terra)
library(geosphere)
```

###### create data

```
lon <- seq(from = 10, by = 3/3600, length.out = 4)
lat <- rep(0, 4)
lon.lat <- cbind(lon, lat)
crs.lon.lat <- "epsg:4326"
grid <- terra::vect(lon.lat, crs = crs.lon.lat)
grid$id <- 1:length(grid)
```

###### set buffer size in meters and create buffer

```
res.7as <- geosphere::distGeo(c(0, 0), c(1, 0))*7/3600
grid.buf <- terra::buffer(grid,
                          width = res.7as,
                          quadsegs = 1)
```

###### plot

```
plot(grid.buf)
plot(grid, add = T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `terra::spin` to rotate vector geometries.

Example data

```
library(terra)
lon <- seq(from = 10, by = 3/3600, length.out = 4)
lon.lat <- cbind(lon, 0)
pts <- terra::vect(lon.lat, crs = "epsg:4326")
buf <- buffer(pts, width=50, quadsegs = 1)
```

The center of rotation is vectorized, so you can do

```
xy <- crds(pts)
s <- spin(buf, 45, xy[,1], xy[,2])
plot(s); points(pts)
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, this way I can keep everything with [terra]

Answer (score 3):

The following is an alternative solution purely based on `sf` - `st_buffer(..., endCapStyle = "SQUARE")` does the job for us.

```
library("sf")

example_point_1 = sf::st_point(c(0, 10)) 
example_point_2 = sf::st_point(c(110, 40))

example_points_sf <- sf::st_sfc(example_point_1, example_point_2) %>% 
                                sf::st_sf()

sf::st_buffer(example_points_sf,
              dist = 50,
              endCapStyle = "SQUARE") %>% plot() 
plot(example_points_sf, add = T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

e.g. like this, starting from your data:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr) ## for convenient dataframe manipulation

angle = pi/4 ## desired angle of rotation

## function to rotate a feature (of class sfc from package sf)
## around its centroid 
rot = function(feature, a = 0){
    cnt  <- st_centroid(feature)
    (feature - cnt) *
        matrix(c(cos(a), sin(a), -sin(a), cos(a)), 2, 2) +
        cnt
}
```

convert from class `SpatVect` to class `sfc` to apply `{sf}` methods:

```
grid.buf.sf <- st_as_sf(grid.buf)
```

rotate as desired:

```
grid.buf.rotated <- 
    grid.buf.sf %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(geometry = rot(geometry, angle))
```

re-convert to `SpatVect` for use with `{terra}` if desired:

```
grid.buf.rotated <- vect(grid.buf.rotated)
```

rotation function adopted from https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf3.html#affine-transformations

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, with my example I never manage to get the nQuadSegs to work - I always get circular buffers when setting it to 1.

Comment: Your `terra::buffer(..., quadsegs = 1)` already produces the desired square. My edited code only takes this rectangular `grid.buf`, converts it to an {sf}-able class and rotates it. If needed, you can reconvert it to a `SpatialVect`(or) and move on with {terra} but it should stay a rectangle either way. Does it not?

Comment: Thanks, now it's working just fine. Thanks much for the code to rotate the features!